# category rest api UTF8 problem

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, utf-8

Magento is creating rewrite_urls for categories by their name
so when the name is full UTF8 like تست or تت it produce empty string for url rewrite like this:

```
 .html
```

so it will insert duplicate url rewrites and this error return in rest call

```
{"message":"Could not save category: %1","parameters":["URL key for specified store already exists."],"trace":"#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\CategoryRepository->save(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor))\n#1 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#3 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/var\/generation\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#6 \/Users\/sinamiandashti\/projects\/magento\/pub\/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#7 {main}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by this data array

```
$data = array(
            "category" => array(
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "parent_id" => 2,
                "is_active" => true,
                'custom_attributes' => array(
                    array('attribute_code' => 'old_cat_id', 'value' => $row['id']),
                    array('attribute_code' => 'url_key', 'value' => $slug),
                ),
            ),

            "save_options" => true,

        );
```

please note that **url_key** in attributes